# Fragment for List items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Android development and struggle a little bit with best practices. It is for a Lego bluetooth project, but this does not really matter here.

I have created a list view that can have 3 different items. My list items have also buttons and subscribe to update from the device. Therefore I created a custom adapter for that:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<Device> devices;

    public DeviceListAdapter(List<Device> devices) {
        this.devices = devices;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object item = getItem(position);

        if (item instanceof TrainHub) {
            return 0;
        } else if (item instanceof Remote) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    // MORE methods
    ...
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Device device = devices.get(i);

        // Disconnect the adapter if is associated to another device.
        boolean isDisconnected = Adapter.disconnect(view, device);

        int viewType = getItemViewType(i);

        if (view == null) {
            if (viewType == 0) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_train_item, viewGroup, false);
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }

        // Only create the adapter when necessary.
        if (isDisconnected) {
            if (viewType == 0) {
                new TrainHubAdapter((TrainHub)device, view, activity).connect();
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

I have shortened the code a little bit. The TrainHubAdapter creates the binding between the actual model (the TrainHub). I got a little bit confused why the method is called to many times, therefore I have ensured that the adapter is only created when necessary.

I wanted to change the layout of my app to tab view and I have realized that there is this concept of fragments, which handles lifecycle management. I think this is exactly what I need here. I do not want to reinvent the wheel and I think this would give me the opportunity to use lifecycle observers and so on.

Is there a list adapter that uses fragments instead of views?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I need a wrapper view for this to host my fragment. So I pass the fragment manager to the base adapter and set the fragment based on the actual item in my list:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<Device> devices;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public DeviceListAdapter(List<Device> devices, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.devices = devices;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = new FragmentContainerView(viewGroup.getContext());
            // The fragment is added by a view ID, therefore we have to generate a ID here.
            view.setId(View.generateViewId());
            view.setTag(i);

            view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
                    // The fragment can only be set if the view is attached.
                    handleAttachedItem(view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

                }
            });
        }

        if (view.isAttachedToWindow()) {
            handleAttachedItem(view);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void handleAttachedItem(View view) {
        int viewIndex = (int) view.getTag();
        int viewType = getItemViewType(viewIndex);
        Device device = devices.get(viewIndex);

        Fragment fragment = getFragment(view);

        if (fragment == null || !IsCorrectFragment(viewType, fragment)) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (viewType == 0) {
                TrainHubAdapter trainHubAdapter = new TrainHubAdapter();
                
                transaction.replace(view.getId(), trainHubAdapter);
            } else {
                ....
            }

            transaction.commit();
        }

        Adapter adapter = (Adapter) getFragment(view);

        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.setDevice(device);
        }
    }

    private Fragment getFragment(View view) {
        try {
            return FragmentManager.findFragment(view);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean IsCorrectFragment(int viewType, Fragment fragment) {
        if (viewType == 0) {
            return fragment.getClass() == TrainHubAdapter.class;
        } else {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I think, that technically the list has only one item type now and we can therefore remove the methods like:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }
```